# Offline PDF creation on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, pdf-generation, windows-phone, itext

Does it exist? I tried to use the iTextSharp, but it is not working. This small example of code is wrong:

```
 IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        Document document = new Document();

        string path = "/first.pdf";

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, store.CreateFile( path));

        document.Open();
        document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Working with pdfs");
        document.Close();
```

The error message is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can anybody help me? Working example code, working dll, anything...

Comment: I don't think that iTextSharp exists for WP8

Answer (score 0):

The iTextSharp from NuGet didn't compiled for the Windows Phone CLR. I'm not sure if there is an official one. You can try compile the iTextSharp source (http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/564/tree/branches/iTextSharp_5_4_2/) as a portable class library, or use an unofficial source like http://itextsharpsl.codeplex.com/.

Comment: The NuGet don't allows me to install if the dll isn't approved, isn't it?

Comment: NuGet don't has a word on which dll you use, so you can add your dll.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't "Add" your paragraph to your document. :)

```
document.Add(p);
```